# Does the Html.fromHtml in android only works in displayed texts?

Tags: android, spanned, fromhtml

Because i'm comparing the user Answer and the correct answer

```
if(etU1.getText().toString().equals(cquestion.get(0).getAnswer()))
```

Example the choice is "Brad's Drink" and even though the user types it correctly it is still wrong because the getAnswer is "Brad%$'s%# Drink". because the ArrayList that I made gets the html texts. 
Is there some way where I can remove the html texts before putting it in the array list?

Comment: The text from an edit text is never going to be formatted like that.  If your data is, clean it up and don't store it that way.  I'm not sure why you're using html at all, and that example of yours isn't html anyway-  I don't know what it is, but its some other encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should remove " ' " before you compare

```
String str = etU1.getText().toString().replaceAll("[']"," ");
String strTwo = cquestion.get(0).getAnswer().replaceAll("[']"," ");

if(str.equals(strTwo)){
////// do your logic 
}
```